# jQuery Mobile won't load OpenLayers Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I'm starting with jQueryMobile and wanted to display a map using OpenLayers. However I'm having a weird issue. Here is the almost working code. Sorry I couldn't make a fiddle, however you can test it easily with copy/paste on notepad or whatever.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
  html ,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-content {
   padding: 0;
}

#pageone, #pageone .ui-content, #basicMap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div id="basicMap"></div>
  </div>
</div> 

<script>
      function init() {
map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap", {
    controls: [
               new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
               new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
               new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
           ]
       });
var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(7.55785346031189,50.3625329673905).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
var zoom           = 3;

map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.setCenter(position, zoom );

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);

var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position);

marker.events.register("click", map , function(e){ alert("click");
});

markers.addMarker(marker);
}


  $(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",init()); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code doesn't show the map.

Now if you take off the following line :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

You can see that the map is showing.

Any idea on how can I solve this ? because I think it can be solved easily but can't see how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it was stupid, if it can interest someone , the css should be like :

```
#pageone, #pageone .ui-content, #basicMap {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display : block;
}
```

And call JS :

```
$(document).ready(init());
```

Don't know however why this works.